# Name an Object in Java and Inheritance

Tags: java, variables, object, inheritance, naming

I am learning Java and like to do it through examples. This is about inheritance and variables.

Animal.java

```
package inheritance; 
public class Animal {
    String name;

    public Animal (){
        System.out.println("A new animal has been created!");
    }

    public Animal (String name){
        System.out.println(name + " has been created!");
    }

    public void sleep() {
        System.out.println ("An animal sleeps...");
    }

    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("An animal *speaks*");
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println ("An animal eats...");
    }

}
```

Dog.java

```
package inheritance;

public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog(){
        super();
    }

    public Dog(String name){
        super();
        System.out.println(name + " has been created!");
    }

    public void sleep(){
        System.out.println("A dog sleeps...");
    }

    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("A dog *barks*");
    }

    public void speak(String name){
        System.out.println(name + " *barks*");
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("A dog eats...");
    }

}
```

Zoo.java

```
package inheritance;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Zoo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog ruffruff = new Dog();
        Dog Fido = new Dog("Fido");

        System.out.println();

        List<Animal> Animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        Animals.add(ruffruff);
        Animals.add(Fido);

        for (Animal AnAnimal:Animals) //for each structure.
        {
            AnAnimal.speak();
            AnAnimal.sleep();
        }
        Fido.speak("Fido");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

A new animal has been created!

A new animal has been created!

Fido has been created!

A dog *barks*

A dog sleeps...

A dog *barks*

A dog sleeps...

Fido *barks*

**Desired Output:**

A new animal has been created!

Fido has been created!

A dog *barks*

A dog sleeps...

Fido *barks*

Fido sleeps...

**Questions:**

How can I name a dog ONCE. So I want to name Fido ONCE in this code. Also I know I can say: Fido.speak("Fido"); 
But that messes up the array. Also seems illogical.

**Why Array?**

I have several others Cow, Bird, etc. I want a generic print out and then a name set to the object when I desire a name to be added.

Thanks for reading and your time! :)

------------------------------After Patricia's tips-----------------------------

```
package inheritance;

public class Animal {
    protected String name = "";

    public Animal (){
        System.out.println("A new animal is born!");
    }

    public Animal (String name){
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("A " + name + " is born!");
    }

    public void sleep() {
        if (name.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("An animal sleeps...");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println ("A " + name + " sleeps...");
        }
    }

    public void speak() {
        if (name.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("An animal speaks...");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println ("A " + name + " speaks...");
        }
    }

    public void eat() {
        if (name.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("An animal eats...");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println ("A " + name + " eats...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not supply the name through the constructor? Usually, one names a pet at birth or on acquiring it, not when you want it to bark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change one of your constructors:

```
public Dog(String name){
    super();
    System.out.println(name + " has been created!");
}
```

to

```
public Dog(String name){
    super(name);
    System.out.println(name + " has been created!");
}
```

so that the Animal has a name, and then use the name in the message.

Comment: So this solves one of the issues. Now the result prints:
A new animal has been created!
Fido has been created!
Fido has been created!

Which is good, but it still says dog barks and dog sleeps. How can I make it say Fido barks and sleeps? even though I made the name variable public its not working.

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question, with the code you are now using, and that shows the new problem. However, you can probably solve it yourself if you think through the principles of this answer, and also do some basic reading and studying.

Comment: The idea was to have it work with the array I can make the program output "Fido is born", but if I create 30 animals and name half of them than it wouldnt work. A friend gave a tip to initialize and create a variable name which helped. Also had to do this:

this.name = name; (as I understand it sets the name variable to the current instance).

In short you gave part of the answer. But it did help thanks.